# "Or" in pathpattern in Intent filter

Tags: android, pattern-matching, intentfilter

How can I say the link has to be "https://www.example.org/kk/article/Details" or "https://www.example.org/ru/article/Details" or "https://www.example.org/en/article/Details"

Need to figure out "kk or en or ru" part in the path pattern in the code below

```
   <intent-filter android:label="login">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="www.example.org"
                        android:pathpattern="/kk or en or ru/article/Details" />
                </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `android:pathpattern` doesn't support all those rules that normal regex does. For more information read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path). The only way to do that is like this:

```
<intent-filter android:label="login">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.org" android:pathpattern="/kk/article/Details" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.org" android:pathpattern="/en/article/Details" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.org" android:pathpattern="/ru/article/Details" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Android is only catching the first pattern, and not the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define all types, i.e. you need to specify data tag for each path value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<intent-filter android:label="login">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
android:host="www.example.org" />
android:pathpattern="/kk/article/Details" />
android:pathpattern="/en/article/Details" />
android:pathpattern="/ru/article/Details" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a old question but maybe is useful for new user. There is a solution more simple and is:

```
<intent-filter android:label="login">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data 
          android:scheme="https"
          android:host="www.example.org" 
          android:pathpattern="/.*/article/Details" />
</intent-filter>
```